# Docker cannot build because can't find matching distribution of a requirement

Tags: python, json, docker

I'm having difficulty getting my app on Docker. Currently I'm trying to build build it, but am running in to an error I can't figure out how to solve.

When I ran `docker-compose build`, it was pulling  and downloading, but when it tried to collect `json`, it gave the error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for json (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

My requirements for my flask app are

```
flask
json
pandas
pymongo
math
heapq
functools
numpy
scipy
itertools
```

My docker-compose file is

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: .
  command: python -u app.py
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - /usr/app
  links:
    - mongodb

mongodata:
  image: mongo:3.2.7
  volumes:
    - /data/db

mongodb:
  image: mongo:3.2.7
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  volumes_from:
    - mongodata
```

My file structure is

```
/myapp
  /utils
    /__init__.py
    /utils_funcs.py
  app.py
```

Comment: I noticed the error message seems to be pointing at a blank version number. `from versions: `. The problem could be in your requirement.txt file. Care to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json` has been added to Python since Python 2.6, you need to remove it from the requirements file.

You also have things like `math` and `itertools` that are part of Python in your requirements file.

The requirements file is for packages that your application needs which are not part of the Python core; basically whatever you install using `pip`.

The easiest way to create a requirements file, is to use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` - this will create a requirements file that only has external requirements.

Your requirements file should look like this:

```
flask
pandas
pymongo
numpy
scipy
```

Comment: What about functools?

Comment: `functools` is in Python since 2.5; [here are the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html).

Comment: Sorry, I meant heapq!